# Detect browser - show different links

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-detection

I am detecting what kind of mobile browser a user has and would like to show the appropriate download link to the right App based on that.  So Android to the Android App, Iphone to the Iphone App, etc.

so this simply puts out a True or False if you are using an iPhone or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <!--
        document.write(DetectTierIphone());
    // -->
</script>
```

I just need a nice simple Javascript if statement showing the iphone DIV if a the code above if TRUE.

```
<div class="iphone">
<a>link</a>
</div>

<div class="android">
<a>link</a>
</div>

<div class="blackberry">
<a>link</a>
</div>
```

Any help getting this started?

Thanks

Comment: Are you distinguishing between versions? Because there are very significant differences between them (especially Blackberry). And what if it's a Nokia N9? (Maemo OS) or a HP Touchpad (WebOS), both of which can justifiably be called tier I smartphone operating sysetms? Or if they user is browsing with the Opera Mini browser, or Firefox Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need hide all divs initially, then use the [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(ua))
   $('div.iphone').show();
else if (/Android/i.test(ua))
   $('div.android').show();
else if (/Blackberry|RIM\sTablet/i.test(ua))
   $('div.blackberry').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the info from:

```
window.navigator.userAgent;
```

it should contain hints on what device the user is using.

This seems to be a ready to use script you can use for it:
[MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/?page_id=60)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) || (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)) {
    alert('iOS');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
$('div.iphone, div.android, div.blackberry').hide();

if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
    $('div.android').show();
} else if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || 
            navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || 
            navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)){
    $('div.iphone').show();
)
</script>
```

I hope this helps!